# Restrict Font Height in Emacs

Tags: emacs, fonts

I am using the default monospace font of Fedora 17 in Emacs (DejaVu Sans Mono). Unfortunately, the bold form of this font takes up more vertical space then the regular form. This means that whenever I type in text that becomes bold, all the lines on the screen move a little down. Similarly for when I highlight regions of text containing bold text.

Is there a way I can force EMACS to use exactly the same height for both the regular and bold forms of this (or any) font?

Comment: This is driving me crazy. Have you found any solution?